# Identification of limestone type

Tags: geology, rocks, petrology, limestone

[image]
[image]
[image]

These are images of a stone found and used extensively in the Jammu & Kashmir region between India and Pakistan. These are called devir or devri in the local parlance.

Following is the description of the stone according to one website that I looked up:

> Devri stone is an impure lime stone extracted from earth at various parts of the Kashmir. The stone is soft in its nature and gives white appearance after carving. The stone can be molded to any form or shape.

I am planning to write a research paper on 'hamam' which is an underfloor heating system used in the kashmir valley, devri stones are commonly used as the floor surface for the hamams. I would like to know if there is an globally accepted name for this type of stone, so that I can report that in my paper. Also, it would make easy for me to acquire scientific data about these stones.

Answer (score 4):

Limestones are usually categorized following the [Dunham & Folk classification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunham_classification). Only very rare or special limestones were given a name and these are often named after the location where they can be found e.g. [Travertine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travertine).

The images you provided are not very explicit which makes it literally impossible to clearly identify the limestone. Please consider next time to upload close up pictures that show the composition e.g. bioclasts and cements of the limestone.

However, there is a [paper](http://www.geosocindia.org/index.php/jgsi/article/download/64163/50131) by the Geological Society of India were the authors date a limestone from the Jammu region which they refer to as **Jammu limestone** or **Great limestone**. The authors suggest that the limestones are from the Precambrian due to [stromatolites](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stromatolite) that were found there in.

I hope this helps!

Comment: http://www.yourarticlelibrary.com/essay/rock-structures-and-their-spatial-distribution-in-the-state-of-jammu-and-kashmir/41388.

Comment: **The Upper Triassic limestone is widely distributed in moraine heaps clothing the north-eastern slopes of the Pir Panjal. It is also from north Pa­halgam, through the head-waters of the Sind, to beyond Gurez. The Triassic limestone has furnished an abundant building material to the architects of ancient Kashmir in the buildings of their great temples and edifices, including the famous shrine of Martand**. Martand sun temple is built out of devri stones that i have referral to. So at least i know the time period of the rocks now.